# Trouble deploying with Heroku

Tags: deployment, heroku

I've posted the same question on Stack Overflow, but I haven't had success. You can see the answers and my responses to them:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68992194/heroku-deployment-difficulty-with-mern-application

I'm trying to deploy a MERN application on Heroku through the GitHub deployment method option on the Heroku website. I know that the Heroku CLI is probably better, but I'm trying to not overcomplicate things for myself at the moment and using their option for GitHub should work too. Here is my build log:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.17.5...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.14
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       added 83 packages in 2.675s
       
-----> Build
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       audited 83 packages in 1.019s
       
       4 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 35.6M
-----> Launching...
       Released v7
       https://react-node-database.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

The GitHub repository that I'm using is here:
https://github.com/phershbe/nodeandreactwithdatabase

The page that I'm getting says "Internal Server Error":
https://react-node-database.herokuapp.com/

The application works for me on my localhost of course. I've tried searching for similar questions on here and YouTube and Google but haven't found what I'm searching for obviously. Any solutions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check your server logs in heroku, when you load the page, there should be a stream of logs, which should give you a better idea)